# How to solve this system of set equalities?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, systems-of-equations

I have been trying to solve this for over an hour but I am still stuck on how to solve it.

Given the sets $A_1, A_2, \ldots, A_{2014}$ and a system of $2014$ equations with variable X:

\begin{align}
A_1 \cup X &= A_2 \cap A_3 \\
A_2 \cup X &= A_3 \cap A_4 \\
&\vdots \\
A_{2012} \cup X &= A_{2013} \cap A_{2014} \\
A_{2013} \cup X &= A_{2014} \cap A_1 \\
A_{2014} \cup X &= A_1 \cap A_2
\end{align}

Determine when a solution exists and when it does, find it.

I usually solve such equations by rearranging them into $(P \cap X) \cup (Q \cap X)=\emptyset$ and then write the condition $Q \subseteq P^C$ and the solutions are all $X$ such that $Q \subseteq X \subseteq P^C$, but I have no idea how to do that with this system. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, your equations imply that for all $i$, we have that $A_i \subseteq A_{i+1}$.

Hence, $(A_i)_{1 \leq i \leq 2014}$ is an increasing sequence. But the last equation tells us that $A_{2014} \subseteq A_1$. Hence, all the sets $A_i$ are equal to the same set, denoted by $A$.

Finally, all your equations can be rewritten as $A \cup X = A$ which is equivalent to $X \subseteq A$.

Conclusion: the system has a solution if and only all the sets $A_i$ are identical, in which case the solutions are exactly the subsets of $A_1$.

(I hope I have not overlooked anything because this solution seems to completely miss the point of "system of set equations" ...)

Comment: Wow, I believe you are right! Seems like I have overcomplicated this problem a lot.

Comment: You're welcome ! A "tip" for this kind of problems (although you may already know it, it never hurts to hear the same thing many times !) is to draw a bunch of things representing the situation. It helps building a better understanding, and have a better intuition.